# laravel 5.1: Auth::check return false in ServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I already looking for similar issues but didn't help me.
`Auth::check` always return false , `Auth::guest` always return true, auth middleware work correct(lets request to continue if user is logged in and redirect user to login page if user is not logged in). whats wrong?

EDIT:
I understood it occurs in provider boot method , so the question would be : how to check user login status in a provider boot method?
this is my provider boot method that share a menu in all views:

```
 public function boot(MenuController $menu_controller)
{
   //dd(\Auth::check()) DOES NOT WORK HERE

    $nav_menu = $menu_controller::roots()->get();

    view()->share('nav_menu',$menus);
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code for us to review.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm using default laravel [authentication approach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication), i dont know which part of code i  should provide here

Comment: Are you using the default `User` model?

Comment: @user2094178 yes i am using default `User` model

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Auth::check()` is using session to check if a `User` is autheticated.

In Laravel the **session is initialized via middleware**, and **all the middlewares execute after the service providers boot phase**

So, in your service provider you can't access the session: it has not been initialized yet

The solution would be to check for authentication and do your work in a middleware, and let this middleware execute after this:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

That is the middelware that starts the session.

Another solution would be to use a callback with a view composer in the service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    //compose all the views....
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
    {
        //works here
        $check = \Auth::check(); 

       //other code... 
    });  
}
```

The callback will be executed only when the view is actually being composed, so middlewares will be already executed and session will be available

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue, and i solved it

here's how i solved it
in my service provider
  `

```
public function boot()
    { 
         view()->composer('partial.navbar', function($view) {
                $view->with('variabelToNavbar', $this->getVariable());
         });
    }



private function getVariable()
{
   if(\Auth::check()) {
          //some code u want
   }
}
'
```

so the trick is to check auth with the function inside servide provider..
its not neat but it work for me